# Invalid object name 'ddl_log' on table drop but object exists?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I´m logged in as a login/user with membership in database role db_owner and trying to drop a table but get error 208 Invalid object name 'ddl_log' in SQLServer 2012.

```
drop table [dbo].[ddl_log]
```

`select`, `delete` and `truncate` work fine, I can add new columns but can't remove any of the old ones.

The table is visible in SSMS and I find the object on dbo (schema_id=1) schema when looking for it in all the following views.

```
select * from sys.objects where name = 'ddl_log'
select * from sys.schemas
select * from sys.tables where name = 'ddl_log'
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME='ddl_log'
select * from sys.sysobjects where name = 'ddl_log'
```

The table was originally used for SQL Profiler in one of our master databases and this db has then been backuped and restored to the current db. I think this is where something has gone wrong but can't figure out what/why.

Does anyone know what information/permissions could be missing on this table that is blocking me from dropping it?

Comment: Is this table in `master` database? Use full  name `DROP TABLE [database_name].[dbo].[ddl_log]`

Comment: Right click on the table and select "View dependencies"...

Comment: It seems like the table has dependencies to a trigger that is on a schema that does not exists in this db (schema_id=0). Any ideas on how to drop that trigger?

Comment: Solved it by deleting trigger under /Programmability/Database Triggers/<triggername> and then I was able to drop my table. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear cache following:

```
Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

or shortcut:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: No, that did not make a difference :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved by dropping trigger (that was linked to a schema that did not exist) with dependencies to table first.